# Laravel job calling class from nowhere?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

I have a job in my Laravel project (v.4.2). which is used for inserting data into database. The class named "ProductUpdate". I use Amazon SQS for queue service.

What makes me confuse now is, when I changed the code in class "ProductUpdate",
it seems that the job is running by using old version of the class.

I even deleted all lines of code in the class but the jobs can still be able to run ( it stills inserts data).

Following is the job class.

The file of this class is at app/jobs/ProductUpdate.php

In my understanding, job class is the only place that will be called from queue, but why it can still be able to run when I deleted all the codes?

```
<?php

/**
 *  Here is a class to run a queued item sent from SQS
 *  Default method to use is fire()
**/
class ProductUpdate
{
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        // Disable query log
        DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

        // Set the job as a var so it will be used across functions
        $this->job = $job;

        $product = Product::find($productID);
        if($product->product_type != 18) {
            // Call the updater from library
            $updater = App::make('Product\PriceUpdater');
            $updater->update($product); 
         }
        // Done and delete
        $this->success();
    }

    private function success()
    {
        $this->job->delete();
    }

    private function fail($messages = array())
    {
        Log::error('Job processing fail', $messages);
        $this->job->delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to cache.

Run this command in terminal to remove all cached data.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**other way:-**

`Illuminate\Cache\FileStore` has the function flush, so you can also use it:

```
Cache::flush();
```

This [link](http://culttt.com/2014/01/06/working-cache-laravel-4/) will also help you :)